# how to use DATE FORMAT in my query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

this works on phpmyadmin , but gives me and error when I am using on the code, the error says ,Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '%'....

whats wrong with my sintax>?

```
    <?php

$database =& JFactory::getDBO(); 

//Declare Variables
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$id = $user->get('id');
$name = $user->get('name');

// Display quizzes
echo "</br>";
echo "Quizzes History for : " ;
echo "<b>";
echo $name;
echo "</b>";


echo "</br>";
echo "</br>";

$database->setQuery(" SELECT distinct qui.title AS name,   

( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(profiles.title)

  FROM jos_jquarks_users_profiles AS users_profiles    
  LEFT JOIN jos_jquarks_profiles AS profiles ON users_profiles.profile_id = profiles.id     
  WHERE users_profiles.user_id = sessionWho.user_id ) AS profile,    
   ( SELECT sum(score) 
 FROM jos_jquarks_quizzes_answersessions     

  WHERE quizsession_id = quizSession.id              AND status <> -1 ) AS score, 

( SELECT count(distinct question_id)              FROM jos_jquarks_quizzes_answersessions            
  WHERE quizsession_id = quizSession.id ) AS maxScore,            
DATE_FORMAT(quizSession.finished_on,'%M %d, %Y') 
 FROM jos_jquarks_quizsession AS quizSession  

LEFT JOIN jos_jquarks_users_quizzes AS users_quizzes ON users_quizzes.id = quizSession.affected_id    
LEFT JOIN jos_jquarks_quizzes AS qui ON users_quizzes.quiz_id = qui.id     
LEFT JOIN jos_jquarks_quizzes_answersessions AS quizSessAns ON quizSessAns.quizsession_id = quizSession.id 
LEFT JOIN jos_jquarks_sessionwho AS sessionWho ON sessionWho.session_id = quizSession.id        
LEFT JOIN jos_jquarks_users_profiles AS users_profiles ON users_profiles.user_id = sessionWho.user_id 
LEFT JOIN jos_jquarks_profiles AS profiles ON profiles.id = users_profiles.profile_id   
WHERE sessionWho.user_id =  ' .$id  " ) ;


if (!$database->query()) { //write data and if error occurs alert
    echo "<script> alert('".$database->getErrorMsg()."'); </script>";
}

//var_dump($database);
$tableStyle = "padding: 5px;border:1px"; 
$tdStyle = "padding:5px "; 
$thStyle = "padding:7px ";

echo '<table style="' . $tableStyle . '" cellpadding="7" cellspacing="7">'; 
echo "<tr> <th style=align:center>Quiz Title </th><th style=align:center> Score </th><th>Maximum Score </th><th> Unanswered </th> <th>Finished On </th></tr>"; 

$row = $database->loadRowList();
foreach($row as $valuearray)
{
echo '<tr style=" align="center">';
foreach($valuearray as $field)
{

echo "<td>$field</td>";
}
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape the ' mark.
So instead of

```
    DATE_FORMAT(quizSession.finished_on,'%M %d, %Y')
```

try

```
    DATE_FORMAT(quizSession.finished_on,\'%M %d, %Y\')
```

Or you can just use double quotes " to start and end the string.

Answer (score 1):

It's because your string is terminated by single quotes `$database->setQuery('` - just change to double quotes and it will work.

```
$database->setQuery(" ");
```

Comment: thanks  seems that error went away, now my php loop is showing an error on the forach loop, can you please advise what is the error telling me,  see modified code