# PHP Date compare with sql

Tags: php, mysql, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to use DATE FORMAT in my query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7072002/how-to-use-date-format-in-my-query)

I have a date from form post as 09-23-2012 and in my sql database i save date with datetime format like 2012-09-23 23:11:13
I want to create a query to compare these two date.
These two date should equal.

Comment: This question already has several duplicates, look at the right column of this page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `DATE_FORMAT`:

```
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(the_field, '%Y-%m-%d') = CAST(:yourInput AS DATE)
```

Or something similar

Comment: It work with DATE_FORMAT(the_field, '%Y-%m-%d') function and i also edit my input variable 09-23-2012 to 2012-09-23